# How to add floating action button?

Tags: android

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5dOR.png)

You can see that there is some text on my `FloatingActionButton`.

How can I specify deisred text on it?

Comment: You see this text because your FAB can't be rendered in the preview. Did you add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your xml's root element?

Comment: i added that but still seeing this text in floating action button

Answer (score 0):

To add some text to a floating button you need a simple workaround as this button doesn't have `setText()` as method. The trick is to use TextView above it.For example, this was you add "OK" to a button

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/s3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Comment: My query is like why iam seeing that text in my floating action button

Comment: I believe you see this text because you didn't specify the drawable for your button like so  android:src="@drawable/my_btn_pic" (you need to have some icon for your btn)

Comment: i was thinking like if there is no resource attached to that floating action button then it will be a rectangular blank space correct me if iam wrong

Comment: well, i've never tried not to attach src but fab is an imageview basically so maybe it's being weird because of this. you lose nothing if you try and set some drawable and then let us know

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should seperate your layout xml for easy to handle .I will explain with example.

content_main.xml

you should add your contents to other layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.baran.playground.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

then you should include it in your main xml

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.baran.playground.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

if you working like this it's more easy to handle your layouts.

then if you want to add text on your floating action button use can use this example :

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"               
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

      <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="OK"
              android:elevation="6dp"
              android:textSize="18dp"
              android:textColor="#fff"
              app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
              app:layout_anchorGravity="center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```